# Problems with Microsoft's Ribbon

Tags: wpf, user-interface, ribbon

I'm having massive issues with the WPF ribbon. Here's a bit of `Ribbon` code. (I'm using `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon`), all of this inside a `RibbonWindow` on .NET 4.5/VS2012.

```
<Ribbon VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <RibbonTab Header="Home" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <RibbonGroup Header="Save/Load" Height="Auto" Margin="0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button x:Name="cmdLoadImage" Click="cmdLoadImage_Click"
                    Margin="10,10,10,10" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Image Source="Images\load-icon.png" />
                </Button>
        </RibbonGroup>
    </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
```

Point 1-2 are bugs.

1. I can't change the height of the `Ribbon`, despite changing the `VerticalAlignment` properties of the `RibbonTab` and `RibbonGroup` to `Stretch`. The visual height remains the same.
2. Changing the `Button` to a `RibbonButton` vanishes the image inside it, while keeping it at `Button` has visual repercussions.
3. How do I make the `Ribbon` span the window as in MS Office? The `ApplicationMenu` going to the top, and so on?

Edit: A free, alternate ribbon control library for WPF will be appreciated. I want to use it commercially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question: sorry to disappoint you Microsoft Ribbon have fixed height so you cant change it.

As for the second question: you should use `LargeImageSource` and `SmallImageSource` instead of put the image into `RibboButton`.

Your third question is not obvious enough, But if you mean that you want to join the `ApplicationMenu` to window title this is the answer: you have to change your window type to `RibbonWindow`:

```
<RibbonWindow xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</RibbonWindow>
```

and in window code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
{
}
```

your design have some mistakes lets fix it.

first of all you have to put the ribbon in grid:

```
<RibbonWindow xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Ribbon Focusable="False" Height="138" Name="MainRibbon"
            VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <RibbonTab Header="Home" IsSelected="True" KeyTip="H">
                <RibbonGroup Header="Tools" KeyTip="T">
                    <RibbonButton Click="btnSave_Click" ToolTipTitle=""
                        ToolTipDescription="" Name="btnSave"
                        LargeImageSource="..\..\Images\RibbonIcons\Save.png"
                        Label="Save" KeyTip="S"/>
                </RibbonGroup>
            </RibbonTab>
        </Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</RibbonWindow>
```

Note: you have to set `LargeImageSource` property To appear the `RibbonButton` correctly.

Good luck.

Comment: The rest is fine, but the `ApplicationMenu` of the `Ribbon` won't merge with the title of the `RibbonWindow`. I want it to be like Firefox: Merged with the top of the `RibbonWindow`. I'd also like to change the `ApplicationMenu`'s text. The `Label` property doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cant put appMenu in windows title you can only put QuickAccessToolbar, also you cant change text of appMenu but can put 16*16 Icon in.